# Phonological rules

Tags: phonology, phonetics

If I were to write a rule dictating that /l/ becomes [r] before a front vowel would it be:

/l/ -> [r] / [V, +front],
/l/ -> [r] / [+front]
or
/l/ -> [r] / V [+nasal]

Comment: It would be none of those, because you don’t specify the consonant’s position in relation to the vowel in any of them. `/l/ → [r] / _V[+nasal]` would be common. Notations using subscript instead of (or in addition to) brackets around ‘+nasal’ would also be common enough.

Answer (score 2):

First, a rule has to follow a standard format for expressing a proposition. If the rule is "a becomes b before c" you write "a→b/_c"; if you want "a becomes b after c" you write "a→b/c_"; if you want "a becomes b when simultaneously after c and before d" you write "a→b/c_d". There is no standard meaning to "a→b/c" (some instructors may accept that as an expression for "when precede or followed by c").

Second, there is no connection between "nasal" and front vowel, so the triggering context would be something like "[V,+front]" depending on the system that you are using. If all and only nasal vowels are front (not a circumstance that exists in any natural language), you could use [+nasal] instead of [+front], and it would represent the same thing.

Then finally, you probably cannot arbitrarily pick features and formalisms, but that depends entirely on the instructor. Some will accept "+front", other will insist on "-back"; some may insist on writing rules entirely with features and not letters, others may not care. So ask your instructor what is acceptable.

Incidentally, I would check your data to see if you have the order of vowel and liquid correct.